# CASE is not working as expected with MAX function in select clause

Tags: sql

I am using the following query to get records:

```
  select       
       MAX(lng_linenumber) as lng_linenumber,      
       str_topic,      
       MAX(dte_expire) as dte_expire,      
       MAX(CASE WHEN CAST(dte_expire as date) >= CAST(getdate() as date) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) as Is_Expire
       from table1       
       group by str_topic      
       order by lng_linenumber desc
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**What i am doing?**

I am using case statement to get Is_Expired 0 OR 1, if expired then 1 otherwise 0. As you can see on highlighted row dte_expire is still not achieved, but Is_Expire value is 1 it should be 0.

Please help me where i am making mistake in query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without sample data and an explanation of what you want to do, then how can anyone else figure out the "mistake"?

Comment: I think you can ask this to @Fahmi, how easily he understood the issue are create sample query as well. I think this is called experience :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below way -

```
select lng_linenumber,str_topic,dte_expire,case when dte_expire >= CAST(getdate() as date) then 0 else 1 end as is_expired
from
(
    select MAX(lng_linenumber) as lng_linenumber, str_topic,MAX(dte_expire) as dte_expire
    from table1       
    group by str_topic
)A
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `max()` aggregation function is causing to get `isExpire = 1`, since `1` is the max value of this column.

Use below query.

```
select t1.str_topic
    , t1.lng_linenumber
    , t2.dte_expire
    , case when cast(t2.dte_expire as date) >= cast(getdate() as date) then 0 else 1 end) as is_Expire
from
    (select       
        max(lng_linenumber) as lng_linenumber,      
        str_topic
        from table1
        group by str_topic) t1
inner join table1 t2 on t2.lng_linenumber = t1.lng_linenumber and t2.str_topic = t1.str_topic
order by t1.lng_linenumber desc
```